# why after adding dynamically pic to divs , the divs arent floating left?

Tags: javascript, html, css-float, phonegap-build

i have 2 divs side by side, but when I'm adding pic to each one the second div goes down.
this is a mobile app (using PG).
the divs look like this:

```
 <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align:center; width:100%">
        <div id="ph" style="float:left;">   </div>
        <div id="UploadedPic" style="float:left;"> </div>
    </div>
```

the 1st photo is added in JS code:

the second photo is added in JS code after another event:

```
 document.getElementById('UploadedPic').innerHTML = "<img src='" + path + imageName + ".jpg'/>";
```

both pic has style of 90% width.

when i put 2 photos in a regular HTML code it works, they're in the same line. but dynamically the second presented below.

help?
thanks..

---

[image]

i meant:

```
<style>
img{
width:90%
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you set the width of the pics to auto?

`<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align:center; width:100%">
        <div id="ph" style="float:left; width:auto;">   </div>
        <div id="UploadedPic" style="float:left; width:auto;"> </div>
    </div>`

Or both to 50% width?

`<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align:center; width:100%">
        <div id="ph" style="float:left; width:50%;">   </div>
        <div id="UploadedPic" style="float:left; width:50%;"> </div>
    </div>`

Answer (score 0):

When using `float` your `div#ph` & `div#UploadedPic` must have to have a fixed `width`

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
    <div id="ph" style="float: left; width: 40%; overflow: hidden"></div><!--add width & overflow-->
    <div id="UploadedPic" style="float: left; width: 50%; clear: both; overflow: hidden"></div><!--add width, overflow & clear-->
</div>
```

You can do this using css `display inline block` also.

Comment: tried. the second pic is still below the first only now its on the right side and not in the middle.
it has something to do with the dynamic writing.. because when i try to put 2 pic regular it works fine.